# How to calculate this $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:** If $$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}[2x+4x^3+\dotsb+2nx^{2n-1}] $$ where $x\in(0,1)$, then$\int f(x)\,dx =\ $?

I primarily need help in starting with the limit.  At first sight it looked like some kind of AGP but I can't figure out which. Any leads?

Comment: Try integrating term-by-term and see what you get. This step needs to be justified, but once you find $\int f(x)$ you should be able to do so.

Comment: INDEED @kccu I see now. It's simply $x^2+x^4+...+x^{2n}$. Thanks